# Binding actual column name inside of the child class: possible?

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have several table sharing n columns, so I think the best strategy would be making an abstract class with InheritanceType=TABLE_PER_CLASS.
Problem is that, even though columns are exactly the same, they could go by a different name.

For example:

```
T1
--name varchar(100)
--surname varchar(50)

T2
--person_name varchar(100)
--person_surname varchar(100)
```

Columns are the same, type is the same..but name is different!
So, is there a way to define an abstract parent class:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
public class Parent{
      private String name;
      private String surname;
}
```

and then, inside of children entities, specify the actual column name?

Comment: In addition to the `AttributesOverride` in the answer below I would suggest a `MappedSuperclass` instead of `InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to add the following to the child entity:

```
@AttributeOverrides({
    @AttributeOverride(name="name", column=@Column(name="person_name")),
    @AttributeOverride(name="surname", column=@Column(name="person_surname"))
})
```